# HTML/CSS Basic Layout Issues

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm designing a webpage that will fit entirely within the browser window, so scrolling is hidden.

I have a headerbar at the top of the page of width 100% and height 40px.  Beneath the headerbar I have a navigation bar of width 15% on the left side of the page, and a content area DIV of width 85% on the right side of the page.

I cannot get the height of the navigation bar and the content area to dynamically extend to the bottom of the page and no further.  What is the best way to make both the navigation bar and the content area extend to the bottom of the page in all screen sizes?

For reference, my **HTML** code looks like:

```
<div id="headerBar">Header Bar</div>
<div id="navigationBar">Navigation Bar</div>
<div id="contentArea">Content Area</div>
```

and my **CSS** code looks like:

```css
#headerBar{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:rgb(35,35,35);
}

#navigationBar {
    width:15%;
    height:100%; /* Note that this doesn't work */
    background:red;
}

#contentArea {
    width:85%; /* if I use any padding or margin this box exceeds the browser width */
    background:blue;
    height:100%;  /* as with #navigationBar, this doesn't work */
    float:right;
}
```

+1 to any solutions!  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "I'm designing a webpage that will fit entirely within the browser window, so scrolling is hidden." — This sounds like you are making some pretty big assumptions about the viewport size.

Comment: I guess I'm assuming the user won't make the viewport size too small.  Kind of like every web developer assumes the user won't zoom way in on their webpage.

Comment: — Bob has a netbook with a 10" screen. Alice has a phone with a 4" screen.

Comment: Actually most developers pick a "minimum" size to support, and then make their layout dynamic enough to support people who have bigger font sizes. Nevermind all the funkiness with mobile devices and their miniature screens.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas — Most developers do not hide scrolling.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/riwette/wFjLj/ here's your code. If I understand you correctly, you want to place navigation and contetn areas on one level?

Comment: it's not phone supported.  This is a Chrome Web App.

Comment: @wagtail — I have Chrome on my phone.

Comment: I see.  The functions I'm performing don't work really well on phones :)  It just wouldn't make sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really, really want to have a layout like this, you can do it with `position:fixed;`:

```
#headerBar {
    background:rgb(35,35,35);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
}
#navigationBar {
    background:red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 15%;
}
#contentArea {
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 85%;
}
```

However, I do not recommend it. It will cause severe problems with small screens etc.

Comment: This is closer to what I may end up doing. If I left the #contentArea position:static, would the problems still occur on the phone?

Comment: On smartphones, you want to hide everything apart from the content. The navigation should be at the top of your page so it doesn't use screen space when you scroll through the content. You can use [CSS 3's media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to provide alternate CSS rules for smartphones, like e.g. `@media (min-width:500px)`. Of course, this is advice for the case that you specifically want to target smartphone users. You may just use scrollable layout to make the site somewhat accessible otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/cFkaU/

**CSS**

```css
html, body { height:100%; }
#headerBar{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:rgb(35,35,35);
}

#navigationBar {
    width:15%;
    height:100%; /* Note that this doesn't work */
    background:red;
    float:left;
}

#contentArea {
    width:85%; /* if I use any padding or margin this box exceeds the browser width */
    background:blue;
    height:100%;  /* as with #navigationBar, this doesn't work */
    float:right;
}​
```

Comment: Like the fiddle.  I'll try this!

Comment: the "html, body{height:100%;}" is definitely what you'll need in a setup like this, but this fiddle still has a scrollbar due to the fact that the contentArea is 100% high but 40px from the top

Comment: I may not mind a scrollbar if I put fixed positioning on everything except the ContentArea

Comment: @Reinder adding overflow:hidden to body will remove all scrollbar.

Comment: @SVS I know, but you basically have content outside of the viewport. You need to realize this when placing anything inside the navigationBar or contentArea. This way, you also could've just put in 'height:3000px', works just as well, even without a height for body & html

Comment: @SVS yes, the contentArea still is able to exceed the height of the screen even though HTML,BODY were set to height:100%.  This is my primary complication with this entire thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#contentArea {
    height:auto !important; 
    height:85%; 
    min-height:85%;
}
```